# How to add customer table to design surface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to do a MVC ASP.net exercise. I have created a MVC 4 application using visual studio.
Then I copied the `nothwnd.mdf` file to app_data folder. then I tried to continue next steps in the exercise.

> 3.Right-click the Models folder in Solution Explorer and select Add | New Item. Add a
>       LINQ to SQL Classes file. Name this file Northwind.dbml.
>       4. Open Northwind.dbml and add the Customer table to the design surface from Server
>       Explorer. Save and close the file. You now have a basic model with which to work.

However, when I try to add customer table to design surface, I couldn't as it is not listed down and tables in nothwnd.mdf. This is my first time with MVC and data connections.

What I have done here wrong? Can anybody give a hint to fix this?

Another question is Can I rename to Nothwind.dbml to anyname?

[image]

Comment: I noticed that Nothwind.dbml is empty. I think ideally it should contain the connection strings.

Comment: You can edit your question, instead of commenting.

Comment: In the screenshot I don't see the database, you need a connection to your database.

Comment: Thanks BadaBoom, problem was my .mdf file was in old version. After I added it through VS as you mentioned I could fix the issue. Thanks again

Comment: I also had problems with that, so I prefer adding files through VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding nothwnd.mdf to App_Data:**

If you added the nothwnd.mdf to App_Data by using Windows Explorer, you have to make sure it's included in your project.

It's better to **add files** directly in the Solution Explorer (in Visual Studio):

[image]

---

**Adding Northwind.dbml:**

1) First of all make sure you can access your database through Server Explorer. You need to connect to your DataBase.

[image]

2) Select **Microsoft SQL Server Database File** as your Data source:
[image]

3) Browse to your mdf file in App_Data - and click OK button:

[image]

After this step you're able to access the database and table(s).

4) Now the exercise tells you to **right-click** on the **Models folder** and add a **New Item**:
[image]

5) Select **Data** --> **LINQ To SQL Classes**:
[image]

Of course Northwind.dbml is empty the first time, because you just created it *(New Item)*. You need to add the table (Customer table) you want to use.

The answer to your last question is of course you can rename Northwind.dbml

Comment: I did the pretty much same except, I added from windows explorer. Can you explain how to add customer table to solution explorer?

Comment: I mentioned, I prefer to add files directly from Visual Studio (right-click on a folder in the Solution Explorer) and not with Windows Explorer.